# How to send messages from a server in a Nativescript + Vue app

Tags: vue.js, websocket, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have a Python Django backend which I use to handle a live chat system, though websockets. In the frontend I a JS websocket, which listens for messages and updates the page async. I use the websockets to send and receive messages to/from the server, trigger webRTC, etc. This works fine in the browser and the chat is real time.

Now I want to create a mobile interface, using Nativescript+Vue, but I cannot seem to find a way to make it work. What would be the best way to send messages from a backend to a Nativescript app?

I know there is Firebase (and other plugins), which offer this functionality and are fairly well documented, but, since I already have a backend it place, I would Like to use that, without adding Firebase or other cloud services as a middle man.

I also could not find something analogous to websockets for Nativescript. The closest thing I came up with is to have a background worker continuously send http requests to a backend api.

What options do I have? Is there a way to implement websockets that I am missing? or some other way?

Comment: a simple google search would have landed you at https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-websockets

Comment: I have indeed found this package. Unfortunately, the author mentioned in the Readme it is not stable and does not fully work (at the date of this comment)

Comment: Please mention that in the question as well.

Comment: @PetruTanas The best thing you can do is, dropping NativeScript before it's too late.. all of the plugins are unmaintained, and NS itself seems to be poorly documented for years. After 2 years I had to drop our major project.

Comment: @Peter , thanks for the advice. I did switch to Ionic in the meantime, but left the question, if someone finds it useful. I managed to solve the problem with Ionic, but before I run into another dead end, is Ionic any better?

Comment: @PetruTanas I'll be honest, I think, currently, there's no perfect hybrid solution, still the best working on separated native code for the different devices. I think the hybrid/multi-platform coding is the future, also I  think NativeScript has been the best candidate, but after two years I think it's not a best idea to commit with them. Flutter is more promising, because of the background is much more professional. Let's see.